# How to disable a Button after use in Nextcord

Tags: python-3.x, nextcord

I want to make a Ticket system with a claim button, everything is ok and works but I want to disable the "Claim Ticket" button after someone used it...

I've tried to google this problem and found no answers that worked for me also I asked in the Python Discord Server, also, no success.

Here's the whole code:

```
class buttons(nextcord.ui.View):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

    @nextcord.ui.button(label="Ticket Support", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
    async def teste3(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        overwrites = {
            interaction.guild.default_role: nextcord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            interaction.guild.me: nextcord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
            interaction.user: nextcord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
        }
        channek = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(f"Ticket-", overwrites=overwrites)
        id = channek.id
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Ticket Support", description=f"Thank you for requesting help.\nState your problems or questions here and await a response.")
        await channek.send(embed=embed, view=butts())
        await interaction.send(f"Ticket created <#{id}>..", ephemeral=True)

class butts(nextcord.ui.View):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

    @nextcord.ui.button(label="Close Ticket", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.red, emoji="")
    async def teste(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        await interaction.channel.delete()

    @nextcord.ui.button(label="Claim Ticket", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
    async def teste2(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        if interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator and interaction.user != None:
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title=f"Claimed Ticket", description=f"Your ticket will be handled by {interaction.user.mention}.")
            await interaction.send(embed=embed)
            interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda inter: inter.custom_id == "teste2")

            async def button_callback(button_inter: nextcord.Interaction):
                butts.disabled = True
            butts.callback = button_callback
        else:
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title=f"You don't have the permissions for this!")
            await interaction.send(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)


@bot.slash_command(name="ticket", description="Setup the ticket system!")
async def ticket(ctx: nextcord.Interaction):
    if ctx.user.guild_permissions.administrator and ctx.user != None:


        embed=nextcord.Embed(description=f"Press the button below to create a Ticket!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=buttons())
    else:
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title=f"You don't have the permissions for this!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: do you know how to grey out a button without someone using it ?

Comment: yes, i already know how to permanently disable a button without someone using it

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@nextcord.ui.button(style = ButtonStyle.gray,label= "Remove Item",custom_id="remove_item",emoji='',**disabled = True**)
```

Read this: https://discord-components.readthedocs.io/en/0.5.2.4/pages/button.html?highlight=button%20disable#discord_components.button.Button.disabled

You can also check out the Nextcord Documentation as well: https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=nextcord+ui+button#nextcord.ui.button

nextcord.ui.button() has an argument: disabled : bool = False.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can [edit your original message](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.InteractionResponse.edit_message) after someone used the button :

```py
class MyView(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @nextcord.ui.button(label="Claim Ticket", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
    async def teste2(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        self.teste2.disabled = True
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
        await interaction.followup.send("The button is now disabled")
```

Doing this will result in the button not being clickable.